# Formula Works in cell but not when used in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The formula I am using:

`=WEEKDAY(Roster!$K$6:$NL$6, 2) > 5`

returns the correct Boolean value however, the conditional formatting is applied to both true and false. I did attempt:

`=IF(WEEKDAY(Roster!$K$6:$NL$6, 2) > 5, True, False)`

and expected the conditional formatting to only be applied to the cells that returned true but it applies to all of them.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

[image: Conditional formatting]
[image: Cells effected]

[image: The range of cells I am trying to apply it to]

Comment: Based on where you are applying it, the formula should be `=WEEKDAY(Roster!K6, 2) > 5`

Comment: I added a picture of the area I am trying to apply the conditional formatting to.

Comment: Assuming there are dates in row 6 that aren't visible, use: `=WEEKDAY(Roster!K$6, 2) > 5`

Comment: Wont that only reference cell K6 instead of going across the range of dates (K6 - NL6)?

Comment: No, it will adjust the column (but not the row) for each cell in the range. If you can. it would be more efficient to do the calculation in a hidden row above the dates, and then refer to that directly in the CF calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same on my PC, entering the date in cells "A2" to "A10". I selected those cells, and used this as a formula:

```
=WEEKDAY(A2,2)>5
```

As you see, `A2` is the top left cell of the range, and as relative cell referencing is used (no dollarsigns), this makes the formula to be "modified" along with the next cell.

Comment: The issue with the relative cell referencing is when I drag the formula down the cell reference moves down as well, but my dates are in a single row spanning across the worksheet.

Comment: =WEEKDAY(Roster!K$6:NL6, 2) > 5 worked just fine!  Thanks for the push!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you, please upvote it for reference reasons (this is how this site works).

Answer (score 0):

Instead  of `=WEEKDAY(Roster!$K$6:$NL$6, 2) > 5` I used  `=WEEKDAY(Roster!$K$6:NL6, 2) > 5` the major difference being I am dynamically applying this formula from left to right so making `NL6` No longer a constant and a variable allowed the formula to be used across the document.